# How to check the particle rate of $1\ m^{-2}.s^{-1}$ at an energy of $10^{12}\ TeV$ from the "Swordy plot"?

Tags: data-analysis, cosmic-rays

On this web page, we see the so-called "swordy plot"

https://www.quantamagazine.org/ultrahigh-energy-cosmic-rays-traced-to-hotspot-20150514/

[image]

At an energy of $10^{12}\ eV=1\ TeV$, we read vertically $10^{-4}$.

The radius of earth is 6371 km : that makes $4\pi R^2=5.1\times 10^{14}\ sr$.

I deduce that the flux for $1\ TeV$ is : $5.1\times 10^{14} * 10^{-4}=51\times 10^9 m^{-2}.s^{-1}$.

But wikipedia claims at this energy : $1 m^{-2}.s^{-1}$.

Where is my mistake?

I don't know if the "GeV" is important in the vertical axis. But if I multiply by $10^9$, it will certain not help to go in the "good" value.

Comment: Also, you calculated surface area, not solid angle.

Comment: @J. Murray : thanks a lot for the explanations and reference